# mvn --version not working?

Tags: java, maven-3

I have problem with MAVEN path 
i have already set all the path but not working please see the below path

Path

```
....;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin;D:\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin
```

JAVA_HOME

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20
```

MAVEN_HOME

```
D:\apache-maven-3.2.1
```

When i try to run mvn --version it will give error of JAVA_HOME please see the error

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory.
JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin"
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

But javac is working fine

Comment: can you double check your JAVA_HOME please?

Comment: Maven clearly states that your _current_ JAVA_HOME is set to `...\jdk1.6.0_20\bin` while it should be just `...\jdk1.6.0_20`.  After changing environment variables, you'll need to close your current command prompt and open a new one to see the change.

Answer (score 4):

`JAVA_HOME` needs to point to the folder which contains `bin/`, `lib/`, etc.

Your variable points *inside* of Java's home folder.

Comment: i want to give reputation but i have no reputation so thanks sir

Answer (score 2):

Change JAVA_HOME `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20`.

`PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` are two different things:

With `PATH` you tell the system where to search for commands. There you should have

```
PATH=...;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin;
```

With `JAVA_HOME` you define where your Java has been installed. Applications using `JAVA_HOME` add the `bin` and/or `lib` directories. There you should have

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20
```

Try the following in a DOS-Box:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20
set MAVEN_HOME=D:\apache-maven-3.2.1
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin
mvn --version
```

Comment: @Jegs Please try the code added to my answer in a DOS-Box. It should work with your environment.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have identified the JRE installation path:

```
Right-click the My Computer icon on your desktop and select Properties.
Click the Advanced tab.
Click the Environment Variables button.
Under System Variables, click New.
Enter the variable name as JAVA_HOME.
Enter the variable value as the installation path for the Java Development Kit.

    If your Java installation directory has a space in its path name, you should use the shortened path name (e.g. C:\Progra~1\Java\jre6) in the environment variable instead.
    Icon

    Note for Windows users on 64-bit systems

    Progra~1 = 'Program Files'
    Progra~2 = 'Program Files(x86)'
Click OK.
Click Apply Changes.
Close any command window which was open before you made these changes, and open a new command window. There is no way to reload environment variables from an active command prompt. If the changes do not take effect even after reopening the command window, restart Windows.
If you are running the Confluence EAR/WAR distribution, rather than the regular Confluence distribution, you may need to restart your application server.
```

Answer (score 0):

You required to set or make sure about 3 variables environment behaviour:
1. M2_HOME: set this environment variable to point out to apache maven directory. Note: must not be point to bin directory.

2. JAVA_HOME: This environment variable must be point to jdk folder, not include bin directory.
3. path: your system/user path variable must be pointing to bin directory of java environment.

this works fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

first set all these things

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20
set MAVEN_HOME=D:\apache-maven-3.2.1
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin
```

check

```
mvn --version
```

if still not working then delete path in environment variables again create it as

```
PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin
```

close previously opened cmd prompt

```
open new cmd
```

and check

```
mvn --version
```

Comment: Removing the PATH is a bad idea... Adding to it is a better idea.